# add dynamic row to Datatable

Tags: java, datatable

I am fetching first 100 rows from db and rest 10000 rows I'm trying to add to the Datatable dynamically. I am trying below way.

```
 pgreq.onreadystatechange = function () {

         if ((pgreq.readyState == 4) && (pgreq.status == 200)) {

                                var a=pgreq.responseText;
                                alert(a);
                                table.row.add([a]).draw( false );
                            }
                        }
```

and from server side the data recieved as here:

```
String a="['"+rs2.getString("I_CODE")+"','"+rs2.getString("I_NAME")+"','"+rs2.getString("UNIT")+"','"+rs2.getInt("NET_AVL_QTY")+"','"+rs2.getInt("ONHAND")+"','"
         +rs2.getInt("INTRNS_SL_QTY")+"','"+rs2.getInt("INTRNS_RT_QTY")+"','"+rs2.getInt("GIT")+"','"+ATP+"','"+rs2.getInt("I_MIN_QTY")+"','"+rs2.getInt("I_MAX_QTY")+"','"
         +rs2.getInt("I_ROL")+"','"+rs2.getInt("AVG_COST")+"','"+rs2.getInt("LAST_PO_PRICE")+"','"+rs2.getString("V_CODE")+"','"+rs2.getString("MAIN_VENDOR")
         +"','"+rs2.getString("VTYPE")+"','"+rs2.getInt("V_MAX_LDTM")+"','"+rs2.getInt("CASHPRICE")+"','"+rs2.getInt("CREDITPRICE")+"','"+rs2.getString("ALTER_CODE")+"'],";

 out.println(a);
```

the data recived as:`['a','a','.........'],['d','d',.....]` his format. but all the data recieved is getting updated in fisrt column of table. Can any one suggest me any idea or any mistake that i am  doing?

**Update**: tried as below:

```
 out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
     String a="table.row.add(['"+rs2.getString("I_CODE")+"','"+rs2.getString("I_NAME")+"','"+rs2.getString("UNIT")+"','"+rs2.getInt("NET_AVL_QTY")+"','"+rs2.getInt("ONHAND")+"','"
             +rs2.getInt("INTRNS_SL_QTY")+"','"+rs2.getInt("INTRNS_RT_QTY")+"','"+rs2.getInt("GIT")+"','"+ATP+"','"+rs2.getInt("I_MIN_QTY")+"','"+rs2.getInt("I_MAX_QTY")+"','"
             +rs2.getInt("I_ROL")+"','"+rs2.getInt("AVG_COST")+"','"+rs2.getInt("LAST_PO_PRICE")+"','"+rs2.getString("V_CODE")+"','"+rs2.getString("MAIN_VENDOR")
             +"','"+rs2.getString("VTYPE")+"','"+rs2.getInt("V_MAX_LDTM")+"','"+rs2.getInt("CASHPRICE")+"','"+rs2.getInt("CREDITPRICE")+"','"+rs2.getString("ALTER_CODE")+"']).draw( false );";
     out.println(a);

     out.println("</script>");
```

Output recieved as:

```
<script>
table.row.add(['a','a',......]).draw(false);
table.row.add(['b','b',......]).draw(false);
</scrip>
```

Comment: variable a can not be String. It needs to be an array and then you need to use it in JS code. Is your code in JSP , just getting that feeling.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to call js function table.row.add(); in servlet?

Comment: no. In JSP you should prepare array object in scriplet tag <%  %>
and then use this array in your JS function.
Looks like you are mixing JSP and JS code.

Comment: It is not mixing anything. I is possible to write js script inside servlet. please refer this link: http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=14853

Answer (score 0):

Looks bit insufficient information. Your a is already an array or most probably multi dimensional array.
So try one of below and let us know if that works.

```
table.row.add(a).draw( false );
```

OR

```
table.row.add(a[0]).draw( false );
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks fior your quick response. I have tried both: table.row.add(a).draw( false ); ptints: <script type=ja in fisrt row and table.row.add(a[0]).draw( false ); prints only <